# python gui - tclerror

Tags: python, user-interface

this code from a japanese professor does not work:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pylab as plot
import networkx as nx

def initialize():
    global g, nextg
    g = nx.karate_club_graph()
    g.pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
    for i in g.nodes_iter():
        g.node[i]['state'] = 1 if plot.random() < .5 else 0
    nextg = g.copy()

def observe():
    global g, nextg
    plot.cla()
    nx.draw(g, cmap = plot.cm.binary, vmin = 0, vmax = 1,
            node_color = [g.node[i]['state'] for i in g.nodes_iter()],
            pos = g.pos)

def update():
    global g, nextg
    for i in g.nodes_iter():
        count = g.node[i]['state']
        for j in g.neighbors(i):
            count += g.node[j]['state']
        ratio = count / (g.degree(i) + 1.0)
        nextg.node[i]['state'] = 1 if ratio > .5 \
                                 else 0 if ratio < .5 \
                                 else 1 if plot.random() < .5 else 0
    g, nextg = nextg, g

import pycxsimulator
pycxsimulator.GUI().start([initialize, observe,update])
```

It gives me an error in the last line regarding the 80th line of this code:

```
## "pycxsimulator.py"
## Realtime Simulation GUI for PyCX
import pylab as PL
import ttk
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import Notebook


class GUI:

    ## GUI variables
    titleText = 'PyCX Simulator'  # window title
    timeInterval = 0              # refresh time in milliseconds
    running = False
    modelFigure = None
    stepSize = 1
    currentStep = 0

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, title='PyCX Simulator', interval=0, stepSize=1, parameterSetters=[]):
        self.titleText = title
        self.timeInterval = interval
        self.stepSize = stepSize
        self.parameterSetters = parameterSetters
        self.varEntries = {}
        self.statusStr = ""

        self.initGUI()


    # Initialization
    def initGUI(self):

        #create root window
        self.rootWindow = Tk()
        self.statusText = StringVar(value=self.statusStr) # at this point, statusStr = ""
        self.setStatusStr("Simulation not yet started")

        self.rootWindow.wm_title(self.titleText) # titleText = 'PyCX Simulator'
        self.rootWindow.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.quitGUI)
        self.rootWindow.geometry('450x300')
        self.rootWindow.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rootWindow.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.notebook = Notebook(self.rootWindow)      
        # self.notebook.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='nswe') # commented out by toshi on 2016-06-21(Tue) 18:30:25
        self.notebook.pack(side=TOP, padx=2, pady=2)

        self.frameRun = Frame()
        self.frameSettings = Frame()
        self.frameParameters = Frame()
        self.frameInformation = Frame()          

      ##ERROR

        self.notebook.add(self.frameRun,text="Run")
        self.notebook.add(self.frameSettings,text="Settings")
        self.notebook.add(self.frameParameters,text="Parameters")
        self.notebook.add(self.frameInformation,text="Info")


        self.notebook.pack(expand=NO, fill=BOTH, padx=5, pady=5 ,side=TOP)
        # self.notebook.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='nswe')   # commented out by toshi on 2016-06-21(Tue) 18:31:02

        self.status = Label(self.rootWindow, width=40,height=3, relief=SUNKEN, bd=1, textvariable=self.statusText)
        # self.status.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky='nswe') # commented out by toshi on 2016-06-21(Tue) 18:31:17
        self.status.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5, expand=NO)

        # -----------------------------------
        # frameRun
        # -----------------------------------
        # buttonRun
        self.runPauseString = StringVar()
        self.runPauseString.set("Run")
        self.buttonRun = Button(self.frameRun,width=30,height=2,textvariable=self.runPauseString,command=self.runEvent)
        self.buttonRun.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.showHelp(self.buttonRun,"Runs the simulation (or pauses the running simulation)")

        # buttonStep
        self.buttonStep = Button(self.frameRun,width=30,height=2,text='Step Once',command=self.stepOnce)
        self.buttonStep.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.showHelp(self.buttonStep,"Steps the simulation only once")

        # buttonReset
        self.buttonReset = Button(self.frameRun,width=30,height=2,text='Reset',command=self.resetModel)
        self.buttonReset.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=5) 
        self.showHelp(self.buttonReset,"Resets the simulation")

        # -----------------------------------
        # frameSettings
        # -----------------------------------
        can = Canvas(self.frameSettings)

        lab = Label(can, width=25,height=1,text="Step size ", justify=LEFT, anchor=W,takefocus=0)
        lab.pack(side='left')

        self.stepScale = Scale(can,from_=1, to=50, resolution=1,command=self.changeStepSize,orient=HORIZONTAL, width=25,length=150)
        self.stepScale.set(self.stepSize)
        self.showHelp(self.stepScale,"Skips model redraw during every [n] simulation steps\nResults in a faster model run.")
        self.stepScale.pack(side='left')

        can.pack(side='top')

        can = Canvas(self.frameSettings)
        lab = Label(can, width=25,height=1,text="Step visualization delay in ms ", justify=LEFT, anchor=W,takefocus=0)
        lab.pack(side='left')
        self.stepDelay = Scale(can,from_=0, to=max(2000,self.timeInterval),
                               resolution=10,command=self.changeStepDelay,orient=HORIZONTAL, width=25,length=150)
        self.stepDelay.set(self.timeInterval)
        self.showHelp(self.stepDelay,"The visualization of each step is delays by the given number of milliseconds.")
        self.stepDelay.pack(side='left')

        can.pack(side='top')

        # --------------------------------------------
        # frameInformation
        # --------------------------------------------
        scrollInfo = Scrollbar(self.frameInformation)
        self.textInformation = Text(self.frameInformation, width=45,height=13,bg='lightgray',wrap=WORD,font=("Courier",10))
        scrollInfo.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.textInformation.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,expand=YES)
        scrollInfo.config(command=self.textInformation.yview)
        self.textInformation.config(yscrollcommand=scrollInfo.set)

        # --------------------------------------------
        # ParameterSetters
        # --------------------------------------------
        for variableSetter in self.parameterSetters:
            can = Canvas(self.frameParameters)

            lab = Label(can, width=25,height=1,text=variableSetter.__name__+" ",anchor=W,takefocus=0)
            lab.pack(side='left')

            ent = Entry(can, width=11)
            ent.insert(0, str(variableSetter()))

            if variableSetter.__doc__ != None and len(variableSetter.__doc__) > 0:
                self.showHelp(ent,variableSetter.__doc__.strip())

            ent.pack(side='left')

            can.pack(side='top')

            self.varEntries[variableSetter]=ent

        if len(self.parameterSetters) > 0:
            self.buttonSaveParameters = Button(self.frameParameters,width=50,height=1,
                                               command=self.saveParametersCmd,text="Save parameters to the running model",state=DISABLED)
            self.showHelp(self.buttonSaveParameters,
                          "Saves the parameter values.\nNot all values may take effect on a running model\nA model reset might be required.")
            self.buttonSaveParameters.pack(side='top',padx=5,pady=5)
            self.buttonSaveParametersAndReset = Button(self.frameParameters,width=50,height=1,
                                                       command=self.saveParametersAndResetCmd,text="Save parameters to the model and reset the model")
            self.showHelp(self.buttonSaveParametersAndReset,"Saves the given parameter values and resets the model")
            self.buttonSaveParametersAndReset.pack(side='top',padx=5,pady=5)
    # <<<<< Init >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    def setStatusStr(self,newStatus):
        self.statusStr = newStatus
        self.statusText.set(self.statusStr)


    # model control functions for changing parameters
    def changeStepSize(self,val):        
        self.stepSize = int(val)

    def changeStepDelay(self,val):        
        self.timeInterval= int(val)

    def saveParametersCmd(self):
        for variableSetter in self.parameterSetters:
            variableSetter(float(self.varEntries[variableSetter].get()))
            self.setStatusStr("New parameter values have been set")

    def saveParametersAndResetCmd(self):
        self.saveParametersCmd()
        self.resetModel()


    # <<<< runEvent >>>>>
    # This event is envoked when "Run" button is clicked.
    def runEvent(self):
        self.running = not self.running
        if self.running:
            self.rootWindow.after(self.timeInterval,self.stepModel)
            self.runPauseString.set("Pause")
            self.buttonStep.configure(state=DISABLED)
            self.buttonReset.configure(state=DISABLED)
            if len(self.parameterSetters) > 0:
                self.buttonSaveParameters.configure(state=NORMAL)
                self.buttonSaveParametersAndReset.configure(state=DISABLED)     
        else:
            self.runPauseString.set("Continue Run")
            self.buttonStep.configure(state=NORMAL)
            self.buttonReset.configure(state=NORMAL)
            if len(self.parameterSetters) > 0:
                self.buttonSaveParameters.configure(state=NORMAL)
                self.buttonSaveParametersAndReset.configure(state=NORMAL)

    def stepModel(self):
        if self.running:
            self.modelStepFunc()
            self.currentStep += 1
            self.setStatusStr("Step "+str(self.currentStep))
            self.status.configure(foreground='black')
            if (self.currentStep) % self.stepSize == 0:
                self.drawModel()
            self.rootWindow.after(int(self.timeInterval*1.0/self.stepSize),self.stepModel)

    def stepOnce(self):
        self.running = False
        self.runPauseString.set("Continue Run")
        self.modelStepFunc()
        self.currentStep += 1
        self.setStatusStr("Step "+str(self.currentStep))
        self.drawModel()
        if len(self.parameterSetters) > 0:
            self.buttonSaveParameters.configure(state=NORMAL)

    def resetModel(self):
        self.running = False        
        self.runPauseString.set("Run")
        self.modelInitFunc()
        self.currentStep = 0;
        self.setStatusStr("Model has been reset")
        self.drawModel()

    def drawModel(self):
        PL.ion() # bug fix by Alex Hill in 2013
        if self.modelFigure == None or self.modelFigure.canvas.manager.window == None:
            self.modelFigure = PL.figure()
        self.modelDrawFunc()
        self.modelFigure.canvas.manager.window.update()
        PL.show() # bug fix by Hiroki Sayama in 2016

    def start(self,func=[]):
        if len(func)==3:
            self.modelInitFunc = func[0]
            self.modelDrawFunc = func[1]
            self.modelStepFunc = func[2]            
            if (self.modelStepFunc.__doc__ != None and len(self.modelStepFunc.__doc__)>0):
                self.showHelp(self.buttonStep,self.modelStepFunc.__doc__.strip())                
            if (self.modelInitFunc.__doc__ != None and len(self.modelInitFunc.__doc__)>0):
                self.textInformation.config(state=NORMAL)
                self.textInformation.delete(1.0, END)
                self.textInformation.insert(END, self.modelInitFunc.__doc__.strip())
                self.textInformation.config(state=DISABLED)

            self.modelInitFunc()
            self.drawModel()     
        self.rootWindow.mainloop()

    def quitGUI(self):
        PL.close('all')
        self.rootWindow.quit()
        self.rootWindow.destroy()

    def showHelp(self, widget,text):
        def setText(self):
            self.statusText.set(text)
            self.status.configure(foreground='blue')

        def showHelpLeave(self):
            self.statusText.set(self.statusStr)
            self.status.configure(foreground='black')
        widget.bind("<Enter>", lambda e : setText(self))
        widget.bind("<Leave>", lambda e : showHelpLeave(self))
```

The lines are the following:

```
    self.notebook.add(self.frameRun,text="Run")
    self.notebook.add(self.frameSettings,text="Settings")
    self.notebook.add(self.frameParameters,text="Parameters")
    self.notebook.add(self.frameInformation,text="Info")
```

The error is: 
TclError: bad window path name ".227211976L"

I really do not know anything about GUIs in Python. Does one of you know what to do? Seriously, I just don't know what is the problem here.

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: This link gave information than your post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47385250/tclerror-bad-window-path-name-python